# how to disable a element in gridlayout?

Tags: android, gridview, calendar, gridlines

i am disigning a calendar application.now i have populated the grid elements.but that grid layout also shows the dates of pervious month.how to disable a particular cell in grid layout? and also if possible let me know how to enable the grid lines?
some thing like this image:[image]

Comment: I don't think that they are disabled the cells just have a different design. If you click on such a cell you'll still get to the corresponding date.

Comment: Thank you! i have implemented that one.what about the gridlines??? is it also some background image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Flo,
Just create state (boolean value) for each element and check it for deciding:  responding/design.